# Read continuous text file with specific delimiter for new line

Tags: r, excel, vba

I have text file like below
Abc**Cdf**Efg
Here "**" is the delimiter for new line
I want to read it in a data frame in R or excel table using VBA
The result should have 3 records.
Any idea?

Comment: To read a text file into Excel you can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140659/vba-excel-macro-to-update-list-via-external-file/31141373#31141373 Afterwards, you can `split()` your data / rows on `**` as the delimiter. That should cover it. Or is there more to it and I am missing something?

Comment: So you have `AbcCdfEfg` and you need `Array("Abc","Cdf","Efg")`?

Comment: @Ralph : Can you give more detail on the split() part please?is this some function within VBA?

Comment: @Vityata : yes.reading in array will solve. Just that the delimiter here is "**"

Comment: yes, [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) is a built-in function which will return an array and split the given input string on the delimiter you determine. So `split("some**text****for**testing", "**")` will return a (0-based) array of `"some", "text", "", "for", "testing"`.

Comment: @MrC - can you give two examples of input string and desired output?

Comment: @Ralph : tried and got perfect result thanks a lot.